# Setting up a localhost and using git as version control on our network or shared drive

Tags: git, localhost

I've never set up GIT before although i've worked with it in the past.

There is only two users and I have our two websites downloaded to my local disk. How do i go about setting up git on our network so we can both push and pull to our repository?

Do I just make a directory like below except to a shared or network path:

```
mkdir /c/git
mkdir /c/git/testrepo.git
cd /c/git/testrepo.git
git init --bare
```

After that do i move all my files from the website into the git folder and if so which folder?

There is usually these folders... hooks, info, objects, refs and then various files like config description and HEAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to get there, but usually you could init the repo as non-bare, add and commit the files, and then convert it to bare.

```
mkdir /c/git
mkdir /c/git/testrepo.git
cd /c/git/testrepo.git
git init 

...copy everything...

git add --all
git commit -a -m "first commit"
mv .git ../git_aux
rm *
mv ../git_aux/* ./
git config --bool core.bare true
```

Edit: Regarding your problem with gitimmersion, I repeated the steps and I had no problems

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm running through git immersion right now to pick up some extra pointers. http://gitimmersion.com/lab_03.html Every time i try to make a file.. the hello.rb file i get an error. Fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you're creating the hello.rb file inside the .git folder, whereas you should do it in its parent folder?

Comment: I'm not sure i get it, I'm pretty sure i just went through all the steps they've asked on the git immersion tutorial. You're saying i should go back down a level in my tree? I only have one folder and that's Hello.

Comment: I added a screenshot of me doing that same gitimmersion chapert without problems

Comment: ahhh, thanks.. i never got the "Initialized empty git repository" message after i echo'ed. and now it's giving me that error message again. Although it let me run this... echo 'puts "Hello, World"' > hello.rb

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I just really need to get this setup on my network and I'm a noob with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to copy everything too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions... but if I already have my files on a local host on the c drive can i just right click on the folder and "git init here"? Would that work to create an active git repository?

Comment: Final question, how can i view/have an online repository?

Comment: I don't use file explorers if I can avoid it, but as I told you, you'd need to turn a working copy into a bare repo if you want to push and pull to/from. To have online repos you can configure them yourself using ssh, but there are already perfect tools like github and, if you want free private repos, geeklist.

Comment: I need to not only view my code/files but to test as well to see if the pages are functioning correctly. Will this cover all those bases?

Comment: nope, you don't serve files from your repo (either local, remote, github, etc). Instead you clone the repo from the webserver and that's where you test for availability

Comment: Where does the clone reside online? Do I have to use my own webserver or is there a free staging area where i can check to see if my new code is functioning correctly..  I'm envisioning .. Local > online staging > final production live

Comment: Nope, you must find a staging webserver by yourself

Comment: Great so i think that answers my question, just use any server atm that i have hosting other sites... create a new directory or a subdomain for the staging?

Comment: I'd rather use a subdomain, that way production IP and staging IP might be in different servers

Comment: Sorry i'm such a noob at this but if they are on different servers. Is it pretty complicated to save to local drive and then push to a dev server and then push to a completely differently hosted server for final production? Seems really complicated. If you could point me in the right direction of a tutorial.. You'd be amazing! =]